# My code won't recognise my class when navigating to a second screen

Tags: android

I'm really stuck here. I'm trying to navigate to a second activity using a button but whenever i try to parse in the name of the class to the `Intent` method, Android Studio throws an error.

In the `Intent` method `toWeightsScreen`, it won't let me parse in a class.

Can anyone tell me what I'm messing up please.[android studio snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBIq3.png)

```
package leith.comstephen.facebook.httpswww.fitnessapp5;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Button navToWeightsScreen = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Firstweights);
        navToWeightsScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent toWeightsScreen = new Intent(this, cut.class)
                startActivity(toWeightsScreen);
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Comment: First of all, class names should use camelcase.
Check your packaging ;) Also, the this in that context refers to onClickListener.

Comment: Don't update the title to say "sorted it". If the problem was solved by one of the existing answers, mark that answer as accepted. If the solution was something else, post it as an answer yourself.

Comment: the answer that worked was this one "Select the three classes (by holding the Shift key and clicking on each) and then, stop holding the Shift key and drag the three selected classes into the leith.comstephen.facebook.httpswww.fitnessapp5 package(folder)... – Dominic Orim"

Thanks Dominic

Comment: Well @Stephen Leith, should I edit my answer (by adding the comment that worked for you) so you can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
navToWeightsScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent toWeightsScreen = new Intent(getActivity(), cut.class);
                startActivity(toWeightsScreen);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `this` in your intent declaration refers to the button's setOnClickListener.
You should specify the actual activity. See the code below

```
navToWeightsScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
    // Changed cut.class to Cut.class to follow coding conventions
                    Intent toWeightsScreen = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Cut.class);
                    startActivity(toWeightsScreen);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but that doesn't explain why android studio wont accept cut.class as a class to pars in. 


I've ammended the code for the schoolboy error to MainActivity.this but even when specifying the activity it won't let me pars in another class.  What am i missing?

Comment: it's not recognising cut.class  it underlines it in red and doesn't come up with autofil seems like I'm making a schoolboy mistake somewhere...

Comment: First of all, change `cut.class` to `Cut.class` (to follow the right coding conventions, class names should be started with capital letters) and then place a cursor over the red line and report the exception it throws

Comment: I also checked the way you arranged your classes. You should place the three classes inside the `leith.comstephen.facebook.httpswww.fitnessapp5` package, or a subpackage inside the package

Comment: How would i go about doing that?

Comment: Select the three classes (by holding the `Shift key` and clicking on each) and then, stop holding the `Shift key` and drag the three selected classes into the `leith.comstephen.facebook.httpswww.fitnessapp5` package(folder).
Your MainActivity.java cannot access these classes because these classes are not in its package and you have not in any way imported them.